# Why my useState function from Context not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database

I learn react and have some trouble with the setMethode when I use a useEffect hook.

In my program I created a connection between react and the database postgres. With that connection I get the data from database and send it as a JSON file to my frontend application. Here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("./db");
const app = express();


const port = 3005;

//Das ist die middelware, dass anfragen vor den anfragen get post put delet bearbeitet
app.use(
    cors(),
    express.json()//Wird gebraucht um den body zu definieren bzw. json files zu empfangen
);




//Funktion listen hat (portnummer, callbackfunktion)
app.listen(port, ()=>{ 
 
    console.log("Server is up and listining on Port: " + port);
    });

app.get("/getRestaurants/:id", async (req, res) =>{
    try{
        console.log("Get One");
        const restaurants = await db.query("select * from restaurants where id = $1",[req.params.id]);
        //console.log(result.rows[0].restaurant_name);
        
        const reviews = await db.query("select * from reviews where restaurantid = $1",[req.params.id]);
        res.status(200).json({
            success:"true",
            data:{
                restaurants: restaurants.rows[0],
                reviews: reviews.rows
            },
        });
        console.log("works");
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

With a list in my Context.jsx file I save my values from the database and use it for my frontend application. Here is my Context.jsx

```
import React ,{useState, createContext} from 'react';

export const RestaurantsContext = createContext();

export const RestaurantsContextProvider = props =>{

    //Definition einer Liste mit []
    const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([]);
    const [selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant] = useState(null);

    //Hier wir din einem Hook die function setRestaurants benutzt um "restaurants" zu verändern, mit einem array
    const addRestaurant =(newRestaurant)=>{
        //...restaurants kopiert die Werte und fügt newRestaurant ein
        setRestaurants([...restaurants, newRestaurant]);
    }
    return(
        <RestaurantsContext.Provider value = {{restaurants: restaurants,//variable
                                             setRestaurants,            //funktion
                                            addRestaurant,              //funktion
                                            selectedRestaurant,         //variable
                                            setSelectedRestaurant       //funktion
                                            }}>    //
            {props.children}
        </RestaurantsContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

To use this function and variables that I implemented in my Context I have to import it in my next JSX file. And that is RestaurantDetailedPage. In this page I want to get the Information about the reviews and the restaurants. So I use a UseEffect hook to get the Dadas from my database and save it in my List from the Cotext. You can see it in my Following Code.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import RestaurantFinder from '../api/RestaurantFinder';
import { RestaurantsContext } from "../context/RestaurantsContext";
import Reviews from '../components/Reviews';
import StarComponent from '../components/StarComponent';
import AddReview from '../components/AddReview';


const RestaurantDetaiiledPage = () =>{

    const{ selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant}= useContext(RestaurantsContext);
    const {id} = useParams();

        useEffect(async()=>{
            
            try{
                
                const result = await RestaurantFinder.get("/"+id);
                 console.log(result);
                 //Bekommt restaurant und reviews
                 setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data);
                 console.log("useEffect");
                 console.log(selectedRestaurant); 
             }catch(err){}

        }, []);//Wichtig, damit es nur 1x

    return(
        <div>{selectedRestaurant && (
            <>    
                
                <div>{<Reviews reviewsObject = {selectedRestaurant.reviews}/>}</div>
                <div>{<AddReview/>}</div>
                </>
                )}
        </div>
        )

        

}

export default RestaurantDetaiiledPage;
```

On my image you can see the `consol.log(result)`from  result
[image]

So I get the data from my database. But why my function setSelectedRestaurant   doesn't work with the command setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data);
My program just stops at this point. I don't get the "useEffect" output from my console.log("useEffect").

Hopefully you can help me

Comment: You have numerous problems in your code: you can't pass an async function to useEffect, you are using JSX tags inside curly braces, etc, etc.

Comment: I just follow an tutorial and try to do it independent. So I don't only copy and paste

Comment: Okay I have the solution.
I have to use two useEffects to rerender it twice

first:```useEffect(()=>{setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data)},[]```

Second:```useEffect(()=>{console.log(selectedRestaurant)},[selectedRestaurant]```
and it works

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found the error. I had an typo in my class Reviews. Anyway I want to give some information about the updating of my value `selectedRestaurant`.

To update the variable `selectedRestaurant` I have to use the function setSelectedRestaurant which is asynchron. Because of the asynchronity I have to render it again with a second `useEffect` hook.

So in my first `useEffect` hook I change the value of `selectedRestaurant` and because of my square brackets it invokes only once.

```
        useEffect(()=>{
            
           const fetchData = async(id)=>{
                
                const result = await RestaurantFinder.get("/"+id);
                console.log(result);
                setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data);  
            }
        fetchData();
        }, []);//Invoke only once
```

With my second `useEffect` I render it again and invoke it, if the value of `selectedRestaurant` has changed. So the code looks like:

```
useEffect(()=>{
          //Do something like:
          if(selectedRestaurant !== null){
          console.log("Selected Restaurant:", selectedRestaurant);
          }
        },[selectedRestaurant]);//Invokes if the value of selectedRestaurant has changed
```

And again it doesn't solve my prolem because I had a little typo but it is nice to know.
Also I am pretty new in react and I hope I explained it right.

Answer (score -1):

As Uncle Bob said in Clean Code, this code not smell so good. There is a bunch of problems here and one of them must cause that you are talking about.

```
    useEffect(async()=>{            
        try{                
            const result = await RestaurantFinder.get("/"+id);
             console.log(result);
             //Bekommt restaurant und reviews
             setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data);
             console.log("useEffect");
             console.log(selectedRestaurant); 
         }catch(err){}

    }, []);
```

You try-catch is useless, so we can remove it

```
    useEffect(async()=>{                         
            const result = await RestaurantFinder.get("/"+id);
             console.log(result);
             setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data);
             console.log("useEffect");
             console.log(selectedRestaurant);
    }, []);
```

Callback doesnt needs to be async, read [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326), Dan Ambromv is one the maintainers of react

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRestaurant = async (id) => {
      const result = await RestaurantFinder.get("/" + id);
      console.log(result);
      setSelectedRestaurant(result.data.data);
      console.log("useEffect");
    };
    fetchRestaurant(id);
  }, [id]);
```

Unless you just want it in our first render, it's ok, but your `useEffect` depends on `id` variable, that could change.
Also, removed `console.log(selectedRestaurant);` because `setState` is an asyncronous function, so the value of `selectedRestaurant` could not been changed

I've created a simple example of this flow and it works

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-violet-fr7np?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have changed my Code but i still not working. The function setSelectedRestaurant not work. And in your program that u have written I also get an error

Answer (score -2):

useContext syntax is wrong.

wrong:
const{ selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant}= useContext(RestaurantsContext);
correct:
const selectedRestaurant = useContext(RestaurantsContext);
In other words, setSelectedRestaurant isn't a function.

Comment: OP is providing an object to the context and is destructuring properties of that object. That isn't the problem.